# SAS_Working Two Dataset

Tags: sas

I want to merge two data sets in SAS. I want to show by using example:

```
 Group     Value
  A         10
  A          8
  A          6
  B          7
  B          9
  B          11
```

it is my first data set. I have the second dataset as well:

```
 Group     Volume
  A         2
  B         3
```

I want to merge these two data sets. The result should be:

```
 Group     Value     Volume
  A         10        2
  A          8        2
  A          6        2
  B          7        3
  B          9        3
  B          11       3
```

I hope, i can explain it. Many thanks.

Comment: Please show what you tried. Did you try merging by group?

Comment: Yes. I want to merge by group. I want to add one more column to first datasets (volume column). As you can see from my result, the value of new column is the same. More detailed, in second datasets there is one value for Group A. it is 2. I want to add this 2 to all observations in group A in the first datasets,

Answer (score 0):

Well one way is to use proc sql and just use a join:

```
proc sql noprint;
     select a.*,b.volume
            from dataset1 as a
       left join dataset2 as b
            on a.group = b.group;quit;
```

or if you want to do it with merge:

```
data combine;
  merge dataset1 dataset2;
  by group;
run;
```

Comment: if these solutions work for you upvote and check answered, thx